# Delete multiple directories in python

Tags: python, directory, shutil

In python, I understand that I can delete multiple files with the same name using the following command for eg:

```
for f in glob.glob("file_name_*.txt"):
    os.remove(f)
```

And that a single directory can be deleted with `shutil.rmtree('/path/to/dir')` - and that this command will delete the directory even if the directory is not empty. On the other hand, `os.rmdir()` needs that the directory be empty.

I actually want to delete multiple directories with the same name, and they are not empty. So, I am looking for something like 
`shutil.rmtree('directory_*')`

Is there a way to do this with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all of the pieces: `glob()` iterates, and `rmtree()` deletes:

```
for path in glob.glob("directory_*"):
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```

This will throw `OSError` if one of the globbed paths names a file, or for any other reason that `rmtree()` can fail.  You can add error handling as you see fit, once you decide how you want to handle the errors.  It doesn't make sense to add error handling unless you know what you want to do with the error, so I have left error handling out.

Comment: Could someone explain how this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: doesn't actually check that it's a directory.  consider including `if os.path.isdir` or something..

Comment: @wim: That's grounds for a comment or edit, not a downvote.  Use the system.

Comment: @wim: I didn't say you were.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you wrote @wim ... use the system

Comment: @wim: I thought it was because you were answering my question.

Comment: @wim: Anyway, it's not clear that the poster wants to specifically exclude files, just that they do want to delete multiple directories.

Comment: Yes, but your code is going to throw an `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory` on any file which matches the glob.

Comment: You could wrap the `shutil.rmtree` in a try: except OSError:` block.  That would solve all the above issues.

Comment: Since it's not clear how the poster wants to handle errors, passing the exception up seems like decent default behavior to me.

Comment: @wim: `os.path.isdir()` is subject to a race condition so it cannot be recommended.